# Stitching secure subscriptions using makeRemoteExecutableSchema

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, graphql-subscriptions, graphql-tools

We have implemented schema stitching where GraphQL server fetches schema from two remote servers and stitches them together. Everything was working fine when we were only working with Query and Mutations, but now we have a use-case where we even need to stitch Subscriptions and remote schema has auth implemented over it.

We are having a hard time figuring out on how to pass authorization token received in connectionParams from client to remote server via the gateway.

This is how we are introspecting schema:

**API Gateway code:**

```
const getLink = async(): Promise<ApolloLink> => {
const http = new HttpLink({uri: process.env.GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT, fetch:fetch})

const link = setContext((request, previousContext) => {
    if (previousContext
        && previousContext.graphqlContext
        && previousContext.graphqlContext.request
        && previousContext.graphqlContext.request.headers
        && previousContext.graphqlContext.request.headers.authorization) {
        const authorization = previousContext.graphqlContext.request.headers.authorization;
        return {
            headers: {
                authorization
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        return {};
    }
}).concat(http);

const wsLink: any = new WebSocketLink(new SubscriptionClient(process.env.REMOTE_GRAPHQL_WS_ENDPOINT, {
    reconnect: true,
    // There is no way to update connectionParams dynamically without resetting connection
    // connectionParams: () => { 
    //     return { Authorization: wsAuthorization }
    // }
}, ws));


// Following does not work
const wsLinkContext = setContext((request, previousContext) => {
    let authToken = previousContext.graphqlContext.connection && previousContext.graphqlContext.connection.context ? previousContext.graphqlContext.connection.context.Authorization : null
    return {
        context: {
            Authorization: authToken
        }
    }
}).concat(<any>wsLink);

const url = split(({query}) => {
    const {kind, operation} = <any>getMainDefinition(<any>query);
    return kind === 'OperationDefinition' && operation === 'subscription'
},
wsLinkContext,
link)

return url;
}

const getSchema = async (): Promise < GraphQLSchema > => {
  const link = await getLink();
  return makeRemoteExecutableSchema({
    schema: await introspectSchema(link),
    link,
  });
}
const linkSchema = `
  extend type UserPayload {
    user: User
  }
`;
const schema: any = mergeSchemas({
  schemas: [linkSchema, getSchema],
});
const server = new GraphQLServer({
  schema: schema,
  context: req => ({
    ...req,
  })
});
```

Is there any way for achieving this using `graphql-tools`? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think you have two problems,
the first one is to get the introspection schema without any authorization key (from what i understood the auth key is received from the client in the connection context).

and the second one is to somehow send on every subscribe operation the auth key.

the first problem is probably solvable with a correct architecture.

but the second problem is not currently supported in `subscription-transport-ws` or `graphl-tools` with schema stitching.
the solution for that will have to expand the current protocol they created.

Comment: Any progress on that?

Comment: @gandalfml unfortunately no progress :(

Comment: Bit I did some progress :) the case is, that each WebSocketLink instance is one ws connection. So, you cannot have one instance for server, but rather one instance for client connection :) I'll try to provide an example on gist in the next week

Answer (score 1):

I have one working solution: the idea is to not create one instance of `SubscriptionClient` for the whole application. Instead, I'm creating the clients for each connection to the proxy server:

```
server.start({
    port: 4000,
    subscriptions: {
      onConnect: (connectionParams, websocket, context) => {
        return {
          subscriptionClients: {
            messageService: new SubscriptionClient(process.env.MESSAGE_SERVICE_SUBSCRIPTION_URL, {
              connectionParams,
              reconnect: true,
            }, ws)
          }
        };
      },
      onDisconnect: async (websocket, context) => {
        const params = await context.initPromise;
        const { subscriptionClients } = params;
        for (const key in subscriptionClients) {
          subscriptionClients[key].close();
        }
      }
    }
  }, (options) => console.log('Server is running on http://localhost:4000'))
```

if you would have more remote schemas you would just create more instances of `SubscriptionClient` in the `subscriptionClients` map.

To use those clients in the remote schema you need to do two things:

1. expose them in the context:

   ```
   const server = new GraphQLServer({
     schema,
     context: ({ connection }) => {
       if (connection && connection.context) {
         return connection.context;
       }
     }
   });
   ```
2. use custom link implementation instead of WsLink

   ```
   (operation, forward) => {
       const context = operation.getContext();
       const { graphqlContext: { subscriptionClients } } = context;
       return subscriptionClients && subscriptionClients[clientName] && subscriptionClients[clientName].request(operation);
   };
   ```

In this way, the whole connection params will be passed to the remote server.

The whole example can be found here: https://gist.github.com/josephktcheung/cd1b65b321736a520ae9d822ae5a951b

Disclaimer:

The code is not mine, as @josephktcheung outrun me with providing an example. I just helped with it a little. Here is the original discussion: https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools/issues/864

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example of remote schema with subscription by webscoket and query and mutation by http. It can be secured by custom headers(params) and shown in this example.

**Flow**

Client request 
-> `context` is created by reading `req` or `connection`(jwt is decoded and create user object in the context)
-> remote schema is executed 
-> `link` is called 
-> `link` is splitted by operation(`wsLink` for subscription, `httpLink` for queries and mutations) 
-> wsLink or httpLink access to `context` created above (=graphqlContext)
-> wsLink or httpLink use `context` to created headers(authorization header with signed jwt in this example) for remote schema.
-> "subscription" or "query or mutation" are forwarded to remote server.

**Note**

1. Currently, ContextLink does not have any effect on WebsocketLink. So, instead of `concat`, we should create raw ApolloLink.
2. When creating context, checkout `connection`, not only `req`. The former will be available if the request is websocket, and it contains meta information user sends, like an auth token.
3. HttpLink expects global fetch with standard spec. Thus, do not use `node-fetch`, whose spec is incompatible (especially with typescript). Instead, use `cross-fetch`.

```js
const wsLink = new ApolloLink(operation => {
    // This is your context!
    const context = operation.getContext().graphqlContext

    // Create a new websocket link per request
    return new WebSocketLink({
      uri: "<YOUR_URI>",
      options: {
        reconnect: true,
        connectionParams: { // give custom params to your websocket backend (e.g. to handle auth) 
          headers: {
            authorization: jwt.sign(context.user, process.env.SUPER_SECRET),
            foo: 'bar'
          }
        },
      },
      webSocketImpl: ws,
    }).request(operation)
    // Instead of using `forward()` of Apollo link, we directly use websocketLink's request method
  })

const httpLink = setContext((_graphqlRequest, { graphqlContext }) => {
  return {
    headers: {
      authorization: jwt.sign(graphqlContext.user, process.env.SUPER_SECRET),
    },
  }
}).concat(new HttpLink({
  uri,
  fetch,
}))

const link = split(
  operation => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(operation.query)
    return (
      definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' &&
      definition.operation === 'subscription'
    )
  },
  wsLink, // <-- Executed if above function returns true
  httpLink, // <-- Executed if above function returns false
)

const schema = await introspectSchema(link)

const executableSchema = makeRemoteExecutableSchema({
    schema,
    link,
  })

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema: mergeSchemas([ executableSchema, /* ...anotherschemas */]),
  context: ({ req, connection }) => {
    let authorization;
    if (req) { // when query or mutation is requested by http
      authorization = req.headers.authorization
    } else if (connection) { // when subscription is requested by websocket
      authorization = connection.context.authorization
    }
    const token = authorization.replace('Bearer ', '')
    return {
      user: getUserFromToken(token),
    }
  },
})
```